# Django. Rest framework. How to generate the same tags?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Digging out the features of **Django Rest Framework**, I constantly come across difficulties. Here it is now. I have photos, each photo has a separate field (photo_1, photo_2, photo_3, etc). These photos need to be uploaded to the same tags, like this:

```
<image>photo_1_url</image>
<image>photo_2_url</image>
<image>photo_3_url</image>
```

My **models.py**:

```
photo_1 = models.ImageField(upload_to=image, blank=True)
photo_2 = models.ImageField(upload_to=image, blank=True)
photo_3 = models.ImageField(upload_to=image, blank=True)
```

My **views.py**:

```
class SerializerImage(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = kv
        fields = ['photo_1', 'photo_2', 'photo_3']
```

In **xml** I get the following fields and this is wrong:

```
 <photo_1></photo_1>
 <photo_2></photo_2>
 <photo_3></photo_3>
```

I need to place all the photos under the tag `<image>`. 
Help advice! How to make all images under one tag. I tried through `self.fields.update`. Tag `photo_1` changes to an `image`, but this can only be done once. Two tags with the same name are not displayed.

**Thank!**

**UPDATE:**
Supplement for **Sreeram**.

After your advice on the output, I get the following result:

```
<example_field>
    <image>photo_1_url</image>
    <image>photo_2_url</image>
    <image>photo_3_url</image>
</example_field>
```

My expected result is independent `<image>` tags, without nesting. Like this:

```
<image>photo_1_url</image>
<image>photo_2_url</image>
<image>photo_3_url</image>
```

Comment: What you are asking is you want multiple tags with same name. Which probably is not allowed right?

Comment: Yes everything is correct. Multiple tags with the same name. As in the example above. `<image>photo_1_url</image>`, `<image>photo_2_url</image>` etc

Answer (score 0):

Use **SerializerMethodField**

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class SerializerImage(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    example_field    =   serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = kv
        fields = ['example_field']

    def get_example_field(self, obj):
        #do your queries, edits here.
        string  = f'<image>{obj.photo_1},{obj.photo_2},{obj.photo_3}</image>'
        return string
```

Comment: **Sreeram**, Hello! Thanks for the answer! But, it turns out not quite what I wanted. Your example gives nested tags in `example_field`. Also, since this is an image, you need the full path in the tags like `ImageField()`. `SerializerMethodField()`, the path cuts off.

Comment: Can you pease post the expected output

Comment: **Sreeram**, hello! I added an update to the main question! Thanks again for helping!

Comment: if you want fields separately, you need to create separate field for each field and a get function for each of it

Comment: Sreeram, I'm sorry, I did not understand. If you have time to write this in your answer. I will be grateful